# Count consecutive days/occurrences based on multiple criteria

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, frequency, array-formulas

In the attached sheet, I have a problem with the below formula.

```
=IF(B2="","", ArrayFormula(max(frequency(if(E2:Z2=B2,row(E2:Z2)),if(E2:Z2<>B2,row(E2:Z2))))))
```

Located in Column D, it is attempting to count consecutive days based on the below criteria:

- Is in use/equal to today (Column B)
- Stop counting backward (past) when it reaches a different entry.
- Not count into the future.

Column C is the expected answer.

The result simply counts all consecutive occurrence across the entire line, this may be in the future or they may have used a different asset for a single day which interrupts the consecutive count, however, it continues after if there are indeed more to count.

Highlighted Green is the range that I'm trying to count.

For reference, Please assume that `Today()` is 01/08/2019 else things would continually change.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FCCnSqMmH5jLFLTQFnmLlIrkiIicjHFvTcP87zBBjPM/edit#gid=0

Comment: See if this link helps https://exceljet.net/formula/count-consecutive-monthly-orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 INDIRECT("E2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(B2:B)+1, MATCH(TODAY(), 1:1, 0), 4))=
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(TODAY(), 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
          ADDRESS(COUNTA(B2:B)+1, MATCH(TODAY(), 1:1, 0), 4)), 1, "♦"))
 ,,999^99)), " ", ), "(\d+)$")))
```

[image: 0]